# Which article must be used here, a or an?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct: a r-uniform hypergraph or an r-uniform hypergrah?

Comment: The rule is to go by the consonant sound, not the consonant itself.

Comment: So, you agree with "an r-uniform hypergraph"? Am I right? When I search both of these statements in Google for the first one there are around 2000 results and for the second one around 9000 results. So, probably those 2000 persons were wrong?

Comment: In all likelihood they are wrong.

Comment: You don't need to search for it on Google. All you need is say it aloud, once.

Comment: @RegDwigнt That's not strictly true, especially not for somebody who isn't a native speaker. If you pronounce *a* as ā, it's not awkward per se to follow it with a vowel sound, it's only awkward for those used to not doing so. But if you pronounce it as ə, then it will be awkward, even if you're not used to avoiding a vowel sound after it. After all, saying *A.R. Uniform* is no big deal, but saying *Uh R. Uniform* is difficult.

Comment: @JasonBassford If someone is using a [mid-tone ◌̄](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet#Suprasegmentals) there  for their [front open unrounded vowel  /a/ phoneme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_front_unrounded_vowel) to produce your putative [ā] [with the indicated pitch](http://www.phon.ox.ac.uk/jcoleman/PROSODY.htm), then those people with have just as much trouble saying that correctly without the mandatory sandhi effect as anyone would who does *not* think in phonemic tones the way for example speakers of Mandarin do.